# how to separately store constituents of a string array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, methods

So, I made a string array with random words.
I would like to know how to store all the strings that make this array into separate string variables.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names1 = new string[] { "Name", "Dog", "Cat" };
        string[] names2 = new string[] { "Ocelot", "Picture", "Stark" };    
    }
```

As I explained in the title, I would like it if I can store these as separate string variables.

Comment: You mean like `string ocelot = "Ocelot";` etc.?

Comment: Why did you make these string arrays? Can you explain why would you assign these strings to variables, since you already have them *stored*? What are you trying to do? Can't you just access the strings by index (`names1[1] -> "Dog"`)?

Comment: How about using a dictionary with key as name of string ?

Comment: Do you want to combine those two arrays into one object or do you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store all the strings from both arrays in to one object you can use `Concat()` and `ToList()` methods to combine the two arrays into one `List<string>` :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] names1 = new string[] { "Name", "Dog", "Cat" };
    string[] names2 = new string[] { "Ocelot", "Picture", "Stark" };

    List<string> stringList = names1.Concat(names2).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(stringList[3]);// writes Ocelot to the console
}
```

or if you want to access the strings by the string value (e.g. "Ocelot") via Dictionary Key (e.g. `stringDict["Ocelot"]`) you can add all the strings to a `Dictionary<string,string>` by using `Concat()` and `ToDictionary()`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] names1 = new string[] { "Name", "Dog", "Cat" };
    string[] names2 = new string[] { "Ocelot", "Picture", "Stark" };

    Dictionary<string, string> stringDict = names1.Concat(names2).ToDictionary(x=>x);

    Console.WriteLine(stringDict["Ocelot"]);// writes Ocelot to the console
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Although I don't know about dictionaries, I understood the first part of your answer with concat

Comment: Dictionary represents a collection of keys and values.Basically you store your data as Key Value Pairs,for example var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(); is a dictionary that has keys as string variables and values stored as int.So for example you can store a Key Value Pair like dictionary.Add("cat", 2); and afterwards get the value by using the key as dictionary["cat"] what gives you the value 2.Here are few links where you can learn more: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8 ; https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to confirm something, can we make two dictionaries with the same key name?

Comment: One Dictionary can't have duplicate keys, but you can make two separate dictionaries that have the same key.

Answer (score 1):

No You cannot create dynamical variables in c#, Though array are specially used when you have to store multiple string variables (we use index to get specific value). Another way we can achieve it is by using key value pair i.e. dictionary object as shown below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] names1 = new string[] { "Name", "Dog", "Cat" };
    string[] names2 = new string[] { "Ocelot", "Picture", "Stark" };

    Dictionary<string, string> stringValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();


    for (int i = 0; i < names1.Length; i++)
    {
        stringValues.Add(String.Format(names1[i] + "{0}", i.ToString()), names1[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < names2.Length; i++)
    {
        stringValues.Add(String.Format(names2[i] + "{0}", i.ToString()), names2[i]);
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in stringValues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", val.Key, val.Value));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

you would get output as

```
 Key = Name0, Value = Name
    Key = Dog1, Value = Dog
    Key = Cat2, Value = Cat
    Key = Ocelot0, Value = Ocelot
    Key = Picture1, Value = Picture
    Key = Stark2, Value = Stark
```

Here you can access variable based on key

Comment: thanks for clarifying that I couldn't create variables to store the parts of the arrays. I was just interested if I could or couldn't store them in separate variables. Also, can you please tell me about these dictionaries that you used. I am new to programming and c#, so it would be really helpful

Comment: Hi, you could click on the given link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8. This would be helpful for understanding Dictionary in C#